# got error "Undefined array key 1" on $helper->getAccessToken() use SDK PHP for facebook API

Tags: php, facebook

Currently i want to integrate Facebook Graph API use SDK for PHP on my laravel framework.  I'm using [facebookarchive/php-graph-sdk](https://github.com/facebookarchive/php-graph-sdk)

i success to get redirect back after login to facebook but i'm facing this issue

> "Undefined array key 1"

and laravel spot this line

> $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();

i don't know sure how to solve it. i will share my full code

function to login

```
public function login_sdk()
{
    $fb = new Facebook([
        'app_id' => 'xxx',
        'app_secret' => 'xxx',
        'default_graph_version' => 'v16.0',
    ]);
    
    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

    $state = bin2hex(random_bytes(16));
    $helper->getPersistentDataHandler()->set('state', $state);
    
    $permissions = ['pages_manage_metadata','pages_manage_posts','pages_read_engagement','pages_show_list'];
    $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('https://mysite.ap.ngrok.io/facebook/callback', $permissions);
    
    return redirect()->to($loginUrl);
}
```

and this my callback function

```
public function callback(Request $request)
{
    $fb = new Facebook([
        'app_id' => 'xxx',
        'app_secret' => 'xxx',
        'default_graph_version' => "v16.0",
    ]);
    
    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

    $helper->getPersistentDataHandler()->set('state', $_GET['state']);

    try {
        $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
    } catch(FacebookResponseException $e) {
        dd($e->getMessage());
    } catch(FacebookSDKException $e) {
        dd($e->getMessage());
    }

    if (!isset($accessToken)) {
        dd('Access denied');
    } 
    
    $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($accessToken);
    
    $response = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,name');
    $user = $response->getGraphUser();
}
```

what is wrong with my code and please help.

Comment: _"and laravel spot this line"_ - there is no array access on that line, so the error must be elsewhere, somewhere deeper down. See to it that you get a proper stack trace first of all.

Comment: hi @CBroe already search but can't find and clue. already tried any possibility but still haven't work